# What is "SW current limit" on Led Driver?

Tags: led-driver, constant-current

I am trying to understand the maximum current capability of this [LED driver IC](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/277/MPQ3362GJ_AEC1-2497272.pdf).

I am pretty sure its on page 4 labeled as "SW current limit":

[image: SW current limit]

But I want to be sure, as I cannot find and have no clue of what "SW" is.
I usually spot the maximum current when its labeled as "N-Mos current", but there is no suck label.

Comment: SW = Switch....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SW is the pin which is connected with the drain of the internal power MOSFET:

[image]

The figure is from page 9 of MPQ3362's datasheet.

Comment: Ah yes, its that pin on the IC!

Comment: Yes, also know as the “Switching node” of a driver/DC-DC-converter